# Central limit theorem. Calculating probability P(N≤49)

Tags: central-limit-theorem

**Here is the problem:**

Apples are being packed in a box. One apple weight is expected to be 200 g with a dispersion of 20 g.

Packing is stopped as soon as the total weight is 10 kg or more. Calculate the probability $$P(N≤49)$$
when $N$ is the number of apples in the box.

I assume that I have to use central limit theorem somehow. I have done similar exercises before but this one is a little bit different and I just can't get it started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_i$ be the weight of $i$-th apple. $P(N\leq 49)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{49}X_i\geq 10000)=P(\bar X\geq 10000/49)=P(\sqrt{49}(\bar X-200)/20\geq \sqrt{49}(10000/49-200)/20)\approx\Phi(7(10000/49-200)/20)$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of $N(0,1).$

Comment: Last = sign should only be an approximation. Also, the "dispersion" is the standard deviation, not the variance.

Comment: A level-2 remark, if I may, now that the obvious points are corrected: usually, one checks at the end that the deviation considered indeed belongs to the CLT regime. Here the normalized deviation is $\frac{10}7$, around $1$, hence everything is fine -- but, to fail to even mention the fact encourages people to apply the CLT in regimes where it is not even relevant.

Comment: I have some questions about this. How does the answer take into account the fact that $N$ could be for example 48 or 47? Also I don't understand the first equality. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Also I noticed that the answer should be $1-Φ(10/7)$